# How to record multiple values based upon a user-entered number?

Tags: c++

My lab professor wants us to make a program that "Use a for loop to write a program that calculates the product of x integers entered by the user; where x is entered by the user as well. Repeat the question using while or do-while."

After further clarification, I realized he meant something like the user enters a number, say 5. The program will then prompt the user to enter 5 numbers. The program then displays the product of those 5 entered numbers. I get how it works now, but i don't understand how I can store all those numbers and bring them out for multiplication later.

This is all I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {


    int numofNumbers = 0;

    cout << "Enter the number of numbers you want multipled: ";
    cin >> numofNumbers;

    for (numofNumbers; numofNumbers > 0; numofNumbers = numofNumbers - 1) {

        cout << "Enter a number"; //how can I record these values then multiply them?
        cout << endl;

    }

system("pause");  
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hint: do you really need to store **all** N numbers when multiplying them?

Comment: Don't you have any idea about arrays ?

Comment: @MuhamamdUsman Arrays are unnecessary for this.

Comment: he was mentioning to store all those entered values as well that's why I asked about arrays @molbdnilo

Comment: You'll fail for not following "using while or do-while". Fix that first of all.

Comment: @MuhamamdUsman That's his proposed solution. The expected solution doesn't use arrays (the course hasn't mentioned them yet).

Comment: We haven't learned arrays yet. This class is an intro to C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Complete code using **WHILE** loop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int n, count = 0;
int input, result = 1;

cout<<"Enter number: ";
cin>>n; // n numbers

while (count < n)
{
    cout<<"Enter number "<<count + 1<<": ";
    cin>>input; // taking input

    result *= input;    // multiplying
    count++;
}

cout<<"Total result is: "<<result;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I finally understand how this works! I also got it to work with a for loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that you need to store all the user-provided numbers in order to multiply them - this is not true. I suggest spending more time thinking on a way to solve your assignment without storing all the passed numbers.

In order to answer your question: the most common way of storing items in C++ is using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). In order to understand what it is doing, you should have some knowledge about [arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) and carefully read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store numbers. Just multiply as a number is entered.

```
    #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;

        int main() {


            unsigned int numofNumbers = 0;
            int product = 0;
            int number  = 0;
            int tempNumofNumbers = 0;

            cout << "Enter the number of numbers you want multipled: ";
            cin >> numofNumbers;

            tempNumofNumbers = numofNumbers;

            while(tempNumofNumbers) {
                cout << "Enter a number"; 
                cin >> number;

                if(tempNumofNumbers == numofNumbers)
                {
                    product = number;
                }
                else
                {
                    product *= number;
                }
                tempNumofNumbers--;
            }
            cout << "product" << product;


        system("pause");  
        return 0;

        }
```

Comment: Sorry @GillBates. Could you please explain why?

Comment: `tempNumofNumbers` has no semicolon, it's not initialized, even if it would be, using -- is not correct.

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks :) Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

If storing N number isn't a requirement, you can multiply values on place:

```
int numofNumbers = 0;
int result = 1

cout << "Enter the number of numbers you want multipled: ";
cin >> numofNumbers;

for (; numofNumbers > 0; numofNumbers = numofNumbers - 1) {
    cout << "Enter a number"; 
    int num = 1;
    cin >> num;
    result *= num;
}

if (numofNumbers > 0) {
    cout << "Multiplication result is: " << result;
}
```

Comment: You should check "numofNumbers". What if it is 0?

Comment: With "numofNumners=0" for-loop exit immediately

Comment: But it will print result as "1". Isn't it?

Comment: @MayurK If "_x-to-the-power-zero_" is 1, then you could argue the product of zero numbers is also 1...

Comment: @TripeHound Yeah I agree. But you can also think 3*2 as putting 3 object 2 times. In that case 3*0  OR 0*3 means putting 3 objects 0 times. Then the product should be 0 right? Confused!

Answer (score 0):

So you managed to calculate the factor of those numbers, now you want to store them to use it later.

You can use a the vector container from the STL to store your numbers. Bellow is an example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<int> numbers;
    int numofNumbers = 0;
    int number;

    cout << "Enter the number of numbers you want multipled: ";
    cin >> numofNumbers;

    for (numofNumbers; numofNumbers > 0; numofNumbers = numofNumbers - 1) {

        cout << "Enter a number";
        cin >> number;
        numbers.push_back(number); // store the numbers
        cout << endl;

    }


    // do what you want with stored numbers in the vector....
    // ....
    //
    for (auto it: numbers){
        cout << it << std::endl;
    }

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For recording input, you could use:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int numofNumbers = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of numbers you want multipled: ";
    std::cin >> numofNumbers;
    double total = 1;
    for (int counter = numofNumbers; counter > 0; counter--) 
       std::cout << "Enter a number: " << std::endl;
       std::cin >> input_number;
       total = total * input_number; //multiple the numbers
    }
    if (numofNumbers > 0) {
        std::cout << "total is: " << total << std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");  
    return 0;
}
```